# ColdFusion Layout Form in Firefox

Tags: forms, firefox, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using ColdFusion 10, and have `cfform` elements as children of `cflayout type="tab"` -> `cflayoutarea` elements.  On the page in question, I have 5 tabs (`cflayoutarea` elements).

Each of these `cflayoutarea` elements contains one child `cfform` element.
Submitting the forms in four of the tabs works flawlessly, however, the last will simply not submit in Firefox (only Firefox).

Source code of `cfform` that will NOT submit within `cflayoutarea`:

```
<cfform method="post" name="official_form" id="official_form" action="forms/soccer_officials.cfm">

... form elements, children of the <cfform> element...                 

</cfform>
```

However, when the page is viewed in Firefox, it closes the form element on page render:

```
<form method="post" name="official_form" id="official_form" action="forms/soccer_officials.cfm"> </form>

... form elements, now siblings of the runtime <form> element ...
```

---

Everything seems to be fine in every other browser, it's just Firefox, and just this one `cfform`.

Comment: The problem is that you are using `cflayout`. Don't use the ColdFusion UI/JS tags/functions, they cause more trouble than they are worth. What you are trying to do can be done as easily (and in most cases, easier) to use JS libraries than it is to use the ColdFusion 'equivalent'

Comment: Adding to Scott's point: External JS libraries also move ahead much faster than than CF, they are much richer than the CF equivalents, and  they have very active communities of their own.

Comment: A small woodland creature dies ever time the CF UI tags are used.  Save the animals and stop using the CF UI stuff.

Comment: Totally agree with you all... this is an antiquated system that I've inherited, and am looking for a quick fix.  Would absolutely LOVE to go all "jquery" on this thing...